# SwiftUI TabView with PageTabViewStyle dynamic height based on Content

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

How do I make my SwiftUI `TabView` with a `PageTabViewStyle` adjust its height to the height of the content?

I have a `SwiftUI` view like follows:

```
struct TabViewDynamicHeight: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
                    VStack {
                        Text("Text \(index)")
                        Text("Text \(index)")
                        Text("Text \(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .background(Color.red)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

This produces an output like this:

[image]

You can see, that the content of the `TabView` is cut off. I'm aware, that I can remove `.fixedSize`, but than the view looks like this:

[image]

I would like the TabView to respond to the height of the content. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach is to fetch content rect dynamically in run-time and transfer to parent via view prefs, so parent can set it as frame to fit content.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

Here is main part:

```
VStack {
    Text("Text \(index)")
    Text("Text \(index)")
    Text("Text \(index)")
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background(GeometryReader {
    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewRectKey.self,
                                  value: [$0.frame(in: .local)])
})

// ...

.frame(height: rect.size.height
         + 60 /* just to avoid page indicator overlap */)
.onPreferenceChange(ViewRectKey.self) { rects in
    self.rect = rects.first ?? .zero
}
```

[Complete test code in project is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TabViewDynamicHeight.swift)

Comment: Hey what library are you using? I tried to get 'rects.first' but the system says rects has no member first?

Comment: @DucDang, it is ViewRectKey preference key, it is declared in different module of referenced test project

Answer (score 0):

I took inspiration from Asperi' answer, however I had to modify some things to make it work in my case.

On the 'Content' of the TabView, I added these:

```
.overlay(GeometryReader { proxy in
   Color.clear.preference(key: ViewRectKey.self, value: proxy.size)
 })
 .onPreferenceChange(ViewRectKey.self) { size in
    if self.viewPagerSize.height == .zero {
      self.viewPagerSize = size
    }
 }
```

Where viewPagerSize is initially:

```
@State var viewPagerSize: CGSize = .zero
```

My PreferenceKey looks like this:

```
struct ViewRectKey: PreferenceKey {
   static let defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
   static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
      value = nextValue()
   }
}
```

In total the code looks like this:

```
@ViewBuilder
func createViewPager() -> some View {
    TabView {
        ForEach(views(), id: \.id) { _ in
            createInformationSquareView()
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .overlay(GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewRectKey.self, value: proxy.size)
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewRectKey.self) { size in
                    if self.viewPagerSize.height == .zero {
                        self.viewPagerSize = size
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .frame(height: self.viewPagerSize.height + 60)
    .tabViewStyle(.page)
    .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    .padding()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works fine with accessibility.

1. Statically define a font for your texts
2. define height for each `ContentSizeCategory` (if you are using system fonts, you can use [Typography specifications](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/typography#Specifications) from Apple HIG.
3. Dynamically generate a `UIFont` using `UIFont.withSize(_)` from `ContentSizeCategory` retrieved using `@Environment(\.sizeCategory)`
4. Display text using with a SwiftUI `Font` based on `UIFont`
5. Use `GeometryProxy` to retrieve width of your screen.
6. From screen width, you can calculate remaining width for your text based on margins and components size
7. You can calculate minimum height with margins and components around your text
8. With `CoreText` and `ContentSizeCategory`, you can calculate height of each text by using `NSAttributedString`, `CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString()` and `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints()`
9. For each item that will be displayed on your `TabView`, there is an height that can be calculated from `@Environment(\.sizeCategory)` and `GeometryProxy`. And you can also calculate the maximum height of all items.
10. Apply the maximum height for all views inside `TabView`
11. Enjoy